# remove html break lines when there is three or more

Tags: php

I have the next in an html file

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

I want to remove the remaining when there is three or more (leave at maximun 3 br)

How can I make this wokr?

I tried

```
 $string =str_replace("<br />\n<br />\n<br />","",$string);
```

but it removes when there is three in a row only, but it doesnt work when there is 4,5 or more

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
function solution($string) {
   return preg_replace("/(<br>\s*|<br \/>\s*){4,}/i", "<br><br><br>", $string);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it might have a problem when a string ends in `"And now four:<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>"`. Sorry, for ruining it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ya it looks like its true. thank you for your insight.